# C# Word Interop Automation 2013 - Set Font color to an RGB value

Tags: c#, office-interop

How do you set the FONT COLOR on a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word C# application?

I noticed the ColorIndex property handles around 20 colors and no sign of allowing me choose from a RGB value ??

This is the code that I cannot make it work:

```
parag.Range.Font.TextColor.RGB = Color.FromArgb(84, 141, 212).ToArgb();
```

The exception i get is:
  **One of the values passed to this method or property is out of range.**

Any help will be truly appreciated !!

Answer (score 3):

Although Color doesn't appear in the intelisense, you can access it on Font like so:

```
parag.Range.Font.Color = WdColor.wdColorBlue;
```

And to create a custom WdColor, you can use:

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(229, 223, 236);
var myWdColor = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor)(c.R + 0x100 * c.G + 0x10000 * c.B);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Font.TextColor.RGB`.

Comment: I tried this in the Immediate window of the VBA Editor in Word, and it worked, so I suspect your error is down to something else: Selection.Font.TextColor.RGB=RGB(255,0,0)

Comment: I'm not sure you should use Color.FromArgb - it might not have the same encoding as VBA's RGB() function.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(84, 141, 212);            
parag.Range.Font.TextColor.RGB = (c.R + 0x100 * c.G + 0x10000 * c.B)
```

Comment: Content formatting plays an important role in stack.